# SQL Server - Delete 65% of content - Is DB shrink okay then?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a database with a very large table. (150 GB)
The major content for the table is a PDF file in a varbinary(max) column.

Now, we have finally moved most of the PDF files away from the DB.
So my task is now to update the table and set the PDF to NULL in 95% of the 1 million rows.

I use this approach to update the table.

- Set the recovery model to simple.
- Chunks of 5000 rows a time is updated. The RAISERROR is just for me to see that something is happening because a PRINT statement is just buffered and only shown when the entire statement is complete.

My question is as follow:

**Is it okay for my to shrink the database afterwards?**

I know about the index fragmentation that this will cause, so if I run an Index optimizer script after, the DB shrink in this case, is fine to do ;) ?

```
DECLARE @msg AS nvarchar(200)
DECLARE @Stopper AS int = 1
DECLARE @IdRange AS int = 0
DECLARE @MaxId AS int = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM EmailLog)

DECLARE @COUNT AS int = 5000

SET @IdRange = @COUNT

WHILE (@Stopper = 1)
BEGIN

    UPDATE dbo.EmailLog
    SET
        PdfFile = NULL
    WHERE InvoiceNo > 0 AND
          Id BETWEEN @IdRange - @COUNT AND @IdRange

    SET @IdRange += @COUNT

    IF (@MaxId < @IdRange + @COUNT)
    BEGIN
        SET @Stopper = 0;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @msg = 'Max @IdRange is now:' + CAST(@IdRange AS nvarchar(20))
        RAISERROR(@msg, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
    END
END
```

Comment: I think one main question here is: How fast do you expect the DB to grow again (or at all?). as when it gorws again it will need to reallocate disk size again which would else be allocated already.

Comment: I have done this on a test db. It went from 135 GB to 48 GB. So yes, it will grow again, but not to the same size, the next few years =)

Comment: Ok. Then I don't see much speaking against it. But lets see if someone brings up another point there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you removed a lot of data and you do not expect the database to grow back at this size for a long time, it would be fine to shrink the database, as long as you reindex (or defragment the indexes) after shrinking.